# .NET Core 5.0 Azure Deployment CORS Issue After Upgrade from 3.1

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops

I'm having a CORS issue happening in my Angular + .NET Core application after deployment, and I am unsure how to fix it.

The message below is happening when I am trying to reach the API endpoint and it only happened after I upgraded the version from 3.1 to 5.0.

> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

What is confusing to me this is only happening in the deployment, not locally. Everything is working as intended locally. What am I doing wrong? I added a snippet of the CORS configuration on the API side.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyCorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));

        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb"));
        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1",
            });
        });

        // configure strongly typed settings objects
        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

        // configure jwt authentication
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    var loginService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoginService>();
                    var user = loginService.GetById(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        // return unauthorized if user no longer exists
                        context.Fail("Unauthorized");
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });

        // configure DI for application services
        services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();
        services.AddScoped<IMenuService, MenuService>();
        services.AddScoped<IViewSettingsService, ViewSettingsService>();
        services.AddScoped<IActionService, ActionService>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserSettingsService, UserSettingsService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // global cors policy
        app.UseCors("AllowAnyCorsPolicy");


        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {                    context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }

        });

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test API V1");
        });
    }
```

Comment: `this is only happening in the deployment` what do you mean? Where do you deploy the app? Can you show yourfull `Configure` method?

Comment: the CORS issue only happens after I deploy the application to azure. The configure method is in the code

Comment: @kjamp Are you deploying with Azure DevOps?

Comment: Yes I am deploying with Azure DevOps

Comment: still haven't this issue after following everything in this thread @JaneMa-MSFT

Comment: @kjamp Having the same issue. Any luck?

Comment: @kjamp i installed the runtime on the server which was required but the issue persists https://dotnet.microsoft.com/permalink/dotnetcore-current-windows-runtime-bundle-installer

Comment: @TM not sure if this would help you but I ended up fixing my problem by changing the settings in the app service plan to the latest .net framework version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS errors in the browser often mask underlying internal server errors. My guess would be that you are running a Windows App Service Plan and have not switched to the early access runtime:

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/11/10/Dot-Net-5-on-App-Service.html

https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Runtime_Support/early_access.md

[image: early access setting]

Comment: tried changing this and still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may arise because you have only enabled CORS on the API side, but haven't enabled CORS on the Azure storage.

You can click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services#enabling-cors-for-azure-storage) to see how to enable CORS for Azure Storage.

Comment: where would I be finding this? enabling cors? the docs are a little confusing. i deployed with azure devops